# Pandas is blocking python when it reads big file

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a 5 G file on my 8G memory MacBook : pd.read_csv(filepath).

I see the memory usage going to 12 G (orange, then red),  and then suddenly the memory usage drops back to 6G, and then slowly goes back up.... And my script doesn't deliver anything, not even an exit error....

What can happen ? Seems like python is completely blocked (ventilator are very silencious...)

Comment: Paging mechanism enters into play. Why don't you read your csv in chunks? If the problem is the compression you can read it in chunks and convert it in hdf5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the file you are loading is far to large reference what your computer can handle. Unless you need to load all the data at once, I would try to load the data based on what you need at that time e.g., load data based on a specific criteria then run your program over those specifics. This should help with the two things. First, you will be able to load your data and run your program. Second, your program will run faster as it is only working on subsets of data at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I went away for a walk, letting the process running, we are now at 28 G of used memory. 24G being compressed by the os. The script finally give something, slowly, but still.